# How can I convert a polyline into a 10m wide polygon, like a thick polyline?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, polygon, line

I want to convert a polyline into a polygon so that the polygon is like a thick version of the polyline.

E.g. if I had a centreline of a river and the river was 10m wide I would want to convert the polyline to a polygon covering the river. Is this possible in ArcGIS or QGIS?

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about ArcGIS Desktop (and whether you're using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap) or QGIS in this particular question.  If the software does not matter, and you are asking about a GIS principle instead, then use the [tag:gis-principle] tag instead.

Comment: The width of rivers fluctuate along their length, does that matter for your purposes? You're not going to be able to improve centrelines to banks, if you want banks you'll need to draw them manually (heads-up digitizing) or extract from multispectral imagery with some sort of supervised or unsupervised classification. If you just want 10 metres either side of the centre a buffer will do it, have a read of your software documentation to see how to use buffer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "buffer" operation to do exactly what you describe. You must be in a projected CRS with the appropriate units to get the result you desire.